# How can I capture a group if it exists but if not, match the rest of the regex?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have the following pcre regex:

```
^(.+\/.*\.php)(\?)?(\/.+)$
```

And this example URL:

```
/subdir/file.php/this/is/a/path/info?par=am1&param=2
```

The regex previosuly written captures in the #1 group /subdir/file.php and in the #2 group /this/is/a/path/info?par=am1&param=2.

I need to split into a 4th group the parameters (after the ?). And get the following:

Group #1: /subdir/file.php
Group #3: /this/is/a/path/info
Group #4: ?par=am1&param=2

Sometimes, the URL doesn't have parameters. In this case I only need to match the #1 and #2 groups.

I've tried this:

```
^(.+\/.*\.php)(\?)?(\/.+)(\?.*)$
```

But if the URL doesn't have parameters, it doesn't match the #1 and #3 groups (/subdir/file.php and /this/is/a/path/info).

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `parse_url` will be better than a complex regex

Comment: @anubhava I've wrote the regex because `parse_url` returns /subdir/test.php/this/is/a/path/info on the PATH parameter, and I need /this/is/a/path/info

Comment: Why don't you combine them? use `parse_url` and then apply your regex to the PATH parameter.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pG8iX5/1 like this ?  `^(.+\/.*\.php)([^?]+)(\?.*)?$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [**`urlparse`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and also [**`preg_split`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split the obtained path:

```
$url = "/subdir/file.php/this/is/a/path/info?par=am1&param=2";
$pth = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$chunks = preg_split('~(?<=\.php)(?=/)~', $pth);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo $chunk . "\n"; // =>  /subdir/file.php and  /this/is/a/path/info
}
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY) . "\n"; // => par=am1&param=2
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/EfZzc9)

Note that using `preg_split('~(?<=\.php)(?=/)~', $pth)` you will get as many chunks with `some.php` at the end as there are such chunks in the path. The `(?<=\.php)(?=/)` pattern matches an empty location between `.php` and `/` substrings.

Comment: Nice solution! It's more simple than my complex regex. Thanks!